# Android :: html pre tag not rendered properly in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using webview to render html tags. but  is not rendering properly on hi resolution screen. other sentenses i am able to read but contents in pre tag is not readable. it is tiny.  Please help.

Comment: How are you doing it? `webView.loadData(yourData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");` is the right way of doing it.

Comment: i using this :: wvBrowser.loadDataWithBaseURL(sBanner, html, "text/html",
    "UTF-8", null);

Comment: Then add this as well: `WebSettings settings = wvBrowser.getSettings();`
`settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");`. Sometimes, it doesn't read  `"UTF-8",` present in `loadDataWithBaseURL` or `loadData` properly and thus fails to implement it.

Comment: still same..doesnt work...only content in pre tag is not readable...

Comment: Post your HTML string

Comment: it works now...i have used media query in css for different screen sizes..

Comment: Using `<![CDATA[` could have worked as well, I reckon.